# Which soundtracks can I get for the Regalia?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

While cruising in the Regalia, one great feature is that you can listen to the soundtracks from different Final Fantasy games. The default soundtracks are:

- Final Fantasy I
- Final Fantasy VII
- Final Fantasy XIII
- Final Fantasy XV: Kingsglaive
- Final Fantasy XV: Botherhood

Are these any more soundtracks I can obtain? If so, where can I find them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually just found a list of every soundtrack you can listen to in game, and the list consists of:

- Final Fantasy I
- Final Fantasy II
- Final Fantasy III
- Final Fantasy IV
- Final Fantasy V
- Final Fantasy VI
- Final Fantasy VII
- Final Fantasy VIII
- Final Fantasy IX
- Final Fantasy X
- Final Fantasy XI
- Final Fantasy XI Rise of the Zilart Original Soundtrack
- Final Fantasy XI Chains of Promathia Original Soundtrack
- Final Fantasy XI Wings of the Goddess Original Soundtrack
- Final Fantasy XI Original Soundtrack -PLUS-
- Final Fantasy XII
- Final Fantasy XIII Original Soundtrack
- Before Meteor: Final Fantasy XIV Original Soundtrack
- A Realm Reborn: Final Fantasy XIV Original Soundtrack
- Final Fantasy Type-0 Original Soundtrack
- Dissidia Final Fantasy Original Soundtrack
- Dissidia 012 [duodecim] Final Fantasy Original Soundtrack
- Final Fantasy XV Original Drive Music
- Final Fantasy XV Afrojack
- Justice Monsters Five Original Soundtrack
- Kingsglaive Final Fantasy XV Original Soundtrack

All of the music not given to you by default is found at stores throughout your trip, so when you stop by a new shop make sure you check out the store and see if they are selling more soundtracks.

Source: http://www.novacrystallis.com/2016/09/heres-music-can-listen-final-fantasy-xvs-car/